# numa_police_memory

Tags: linux, assembly, mips, inline-assembly, numa

I'm debugging NUMACTL on MIPS machine. In numa_police_memory() API, we have:

```
void numa_police_memory(void *mem, size_t size)
{
        int pagesize = numa_pagesize_int();
        unsigned long i;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i += pagesize)
                asm volatile("" :: "r" (((volatile unsigned char *)mem)[i]));
}
```

It seems "asm volatile("" :: "r" (((volatile unsigned char *)mem)[i]));" is used for reading a VM so that all the memory applied by previous mmap will be allocated onto some specific physical memory. But how does this asm code work? I can't read assembly language! Why is the first double quote empty???

Thanks

Comment: Interesting, you have a MIPS computer with multiple memory domains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, there is no assembly code in this snippet at all, though the `asm` statement is used.  It contains a blank assembly "program", an empty list of outputs, and a list of inputs.  The input specification forces `((volatile unsigned char *)mem)[i]` to be in a register.  So all this bit of magic will do is generate a load of the first byte of each page (pre-fault the pages).

Comment: Register.  See the [GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/gcc/Simple-Constraints.html) for more info.  What's happening here is the `asm` statement is telling GCC that the value needs to be in a register before the inline assembly is executed.  GCC doesn't care that the assembly code is actually blank, and still produces a load.